# How to serialize and unserialize array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to serialize this:

```
$product_detail = array(
            'product_name' => $_POST['product_name'],
            'product_price' => $_POST['product_price'],
            'product_description' => $_POST['product_description'],
            'product_size' => $_POST['product_size'] // this line get the item in option "value" 
        );
$product_detail=serialize($product_detail); //convert array into string.
```

But when I un serialize, and enter that into db, this error shows :

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`0`) VALUES ('')
```

If I don't unserialize it shows:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`QA92000I` like it alotLarge) VALUES ('')
```

Tell me where i am getting wrong i am using codeigniter

Comment: this is your controller code and you want to insert this array into database??

Comment: Yes this is my controller code after unserialized i transfer it to model then insert in db

Comment: without unserialize it show values only and dont shows keys(table columns name)

Comment: Please show the PHP code you use to create the Query. That is most likely where your error is

Comment: Put var_damp($product_detail) before serialize and after unserialize. It will help to find  the answer

Answer (score 2):

No need to  serialize and unserialize array in codeigniter while insert it into database:-

You can insert it using this:-

//this is controller code:-

```
function product()
{
 $this->load->model("your_model");// load your model file
    $product_detail = array(
                'product_name' => $_POST['product_name'],
                'product_price' => $_POST['product_price'],
                'product_description' => $_POST['product_description'],
                'product_size' => $_POST['product_size'] // this line get the item in option "value" 
        );
$this->your_model->product($product_detail);// pass your array directly to your model file

}

// this is your model code
function product($product_detail)
{
$this->db->insert('products',$product_detail)
}
```

Comment: dear problem is need to serialize, because it is my requirement

Comment: i don't understand why serialize is required. you can do it in simple way

Comment: Because I need to store that array in session table. for that i need to serialize and then extract it from session and then un serialize

Answer (score 1):

Thats how i un serialize:

```
$product_detail=unserialize($product_detail);
```

That is how I transfer variable to model:

```
$this->Product_area_model->product_add_new($product_detail);
```

This is my query:

```
$this->db->insert('products',$product_detail);
```

Comment: Is this answer or new information for your question?If so you can edit the question.Please do not write information as answer.

Comment: System dont allows me to write such a big reply. So I entered it as answer. I am new to stack exchange.

Comment: I did not told you to write it as comment.I told you to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to serialize those fields and store them in a single field on the row, thats fine, but you need to know what field in the table you want to place the serialized data into so this is the basic flow

```
function product($id)
{
   $this->load->model("your_model");// load your model file

   $product_detail = array(
            'product_name' => $_POST['product_name'],
            'product_price' => $_POST['product_price'],
            'product_description' => $_POST['product_description'],
            'product_size' => $_POST['product_size'] 
        );
   $product_detail=serialize($product_detail); 

   $product = array('id' => $id,
                    'product_details' = $product_detail
              );
   $this->your_model->insert($product);
}
```